# Installing nokogiri Mac OS X 10.8.2 XCode installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, nokogiri

Trying to install nokogiri on Mountain Lion. I was using ruby 1.8.7 but just upgraded to 1.9.3 but it stopped the bundle install from working.

Incidentally, I could get round this problem by uninstalling ruby 1.9.3 and reverting to 1.8.7. however this is obviously a suboptimal solution since I don't want to be stuck on 1.8.7 for the rest of time...

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:sample_app user$ ls
Gemfile     app     doc     script
Gemfile.lock    config      lib     spec
README.md   config.ru   log     tmp
Rakefile    db      public      vendor
Ravins-MacBook-Pro:sample_app user$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:263: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.8) 
Using builder (3.0.3) 
Using activemodel (3.2.8) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.8) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.8) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.8) 
Using activeresource (3.2.8) 
Using addressable (2.3.2) 
Installing nokogiri (1.5.5) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
extconf.rb:86: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:114:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have downloaded XCODE including the developer tools, so I do not know why it won't install nokogiri...

When I try to install nokogiri directly, I get:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:86: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:114:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ravinthambapillai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

[image: developer tools components tab]
thanks,

[image: developer tools install photo]

Comment: I assume that you go the same results trying to install nokogiri directly outside of the bundle?

Comment: I just added the error message I get when trying to install nokogiri directly into the answer

Comment: @ravin it's not the issue of command line tools..

Comment: Ravin, Mohit's answer looks good. If it fixed it, you should Mark as Answer. I would like to know the solution for future reference.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After short research I find out what problem can be simply solved by creating symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

works for me hope for you too

```
gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/morozovm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***

bash-3.2$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
Password:
bash-3.2$ gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.5.6
1 gem installed
```

Comment: It works for me too. I knew it was this kind of problem but seriously... How to lose your time...

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me. Had the problem when upgraded Xcode to version 5 (Rails 4, Ruby 2.0.0-p195)

Answer (score 1):

Try these. I faced the same issue and it worked for me. First install libxml2 and then run bundler again.

```
 brew install libxml2
 brew link libxml2
```

Source:  http://decielo.com/articles/11/rails-3-on-lion-hey-ho-lets-go

**Update:**

I am hoping that you have homebrew installed. If you don't have homebrew then I will suggest you to install homebrew and then install libxml2 and then bundler. Don't use mac ports in case you don't have homebrew.

**Update:**

It's not an issue of command line tools. It's failing at libxml. Try to read the error and you will see

```
    checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

And that's the issue

Comment: Sadly this hasn't helped me (I have an identical problem). I've linked `libxml2` and `libxslt` but I'm still getting the `libxml/parser.h` @Ravin was having above. Any further suggestions?

Comment: U getting same error?  checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***

Answer (score -3):

I think this is the most important bit of the error message:

```
warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

Some part of the build process is whining that that directory has permissions such that anyone can write to it. You could try to hunt it down - or you could fix it.