# Bundle install is trying to install gems not included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason when i enter

```
$ bundle install
```

it outputs this (Nokogiri is not in this gemfile). I am new to mac so it could be something to do with rvm.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activesupport 4.0.5
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.5
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.5
Using activemodel 4.0.5
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.5
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using mini_portile 0.6.0
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Harry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Harry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Harry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Harry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I even tried following the directions on the nokogiri website (even though it wasn't in this gemfile) but it still didn't work. I also even tried commenting out nokogiri in a different gemfile to see if that was the problem but still no success.

**UPDATE**
For somereason now in this directory it is giving me, "Rails is not installed on this computer" however if i cd out of this directory and type rails -v it works fine.

Comment: maybe try deleting Gemfile.lock

Comment: I've seen that there is other question like yours with same [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657558/installing-nokogiri-mac-os-x-10-8-2-xcode-installed). Was answer there helpful for you?

Comment: Are you install runtime dependency gem `mini_portile`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528839/installing-nokogiri-fails-libiconv-missing

Comment: @manu29.d Thanks, I have already had a look and tried those methods same with Milos. Any other ideas on how I could fix this error? For some reason now only in this directory it is saying that rails is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

There are dependency gems which you don't include in the gemfile, several gems use dependency gems for their operation, e.g. `devise` gem, you only include this gem into your gem file but it has dependency gems which get installed along with `devise` gem, you can check dependency gems in your `Gemfile.lock` file, here's the example for `devise` gem

```
devise (3.2.0)
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
  railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  warden (~> 1.2.3)
```

`bcrypt-ruby` and other gems are dependency gems here

Comment: I had a look in my gemlock file and there were no mentions of nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, bundler also (always) installs any requirements of all gems you want to install. To see which gem requires nokogiri, take a look at `Gemfile.lock`, as this gives a complete list of all installed gems, versions and their requirements (including versions)

To solve your problem, you should install `libiconv` as stated in the error message.

Comment: I tried installing libiconv and then linking it but I am still getting the error

Comment: Have you tried installing nokogiri using system libraries by calling `bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries` before `bundle install`?