# Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find nokogiri-1.5.5 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a rake task from script using crontab @reboot

The crontab looks like this:

```
@reboot cd /home/me/apps/packaged/X/ && ./resque_startup.sh > /home/me/sss.txt 2>&1
```

the resque_startup script (Yes the code can be more idiomatic but thats not the case) :

> ```
> if [ -z ${1+x} ]; then
>   RAILS_ENV=xxx /usr/local/bin/rake deploy:resque
> else
>  if [ $1 = 'start' ]; then
>   RAILS_ENV=xxx rake deploy:resque
> elif [ $1 = 'stop' ]; then
>   echo "stop resque"
> else
>   echo "Invalid command, use start|stop"
> fi
> fi
> ```

I get the following error:

> ```
> rake aborted!
> Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find nokogiri-1.5.5 in any of the sources
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
> /home/me/apps/packaged/X/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
> /home/me/apps/packaged/X/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
> /home/me/apps/packaged/X/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)
> ```

note that if i run the script manualy from X folder everything works fine

Thanks.

Comment: Install Xcode command line tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568120/error-when-installing-nokogiri-on-mac-withsudo-gem-install-nokogiri

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
bundle install --path vendor/cache
```

Comment: If ruby installed with RVM ,It disable 'SHARED_GEMS'  and install gems in project folder.